# To increment slider value by 10

Tags: iphone, uislider

I have a slider. Minimum value of this is 0sec and maximum value is 3min(or 180 sec). I want to increment the slider value by 10 sec. How can I get this? Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you want the slider to increment up/down in steps of 10...

Hook up the slider's **value changed** event in IB (or `UIControlEventValueChanged` in code) to a method in your view controller such as:

```
- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(id)sender {
    int value = (int)[self.slider value];   
    int stepSize = 10;
    value = (value - value % stepSize);
    // Set the new value.
    self.sliderValue = value; 
}
```

The `self.sliderValue` is a separate integer property to track the value (rather than changing the underlying value of the slider causing UI issues)

Comment: `int stepSize = 10.0f;` is rather pointless, `int stepSize = 10;` will suffice.

Comment: Also, I can't test, but will `self.sliderValue = value;` trigger a `sliderValueChanged:`? If so, this will cause a stack overflow.

Comment: No, as mentioned in my answer, this is a separate property to store the stepped slider value. It's not directly linked to the UISlider.

Comment: Oh I get it now, this way makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
[mySlider setValue:([mySlider value]+10) animated:YES];
```

Turn "animated" to NO if you do not want your slider to animate to the new value.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the slider to increment only in amounts of 10, then have the slider go from 0 to 18, and whenever you use or display the value, multiply it by 10.